# Can we add a wallpaper for the class extending android.app.Application?

Tags: java, android-layout, android

I am loading some required resources in a global class which extends Application.
Since it runs first as soon as we launch the application, it takes some time to start first activity which results in blank screen for few seconds during launch.

Can we add a wallpaper or a gif which displays that the application is loading instead in place of blank screen?

If yes, please help me out how to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a background image in your layout, then if you need to load huge information when started your application, you can load this info in background using asynctask or service or thread.

Comment: Thanks for replying!
Are you recommending not to use Global Application class to load huge information (like loading soundpools) instead load them in activity using AsyncTask?